# Is it possible to shrink the width (responsive) of an image beside a floated element?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to convert an existing design to a (somewhat) responsive layout.
It has a floated box (blue box) in the upper left corner, and the rest of the content should be floated around (text and green box, representing an image).

[image: basic layout structure in responsive container]

I'm looking for a way to adjust the size of the image (green box) as long as it is beside the floated blue box, but returning to normal size when being pushed beneath it by the other content (lorem ipsum).

My normal approach would be to say `max-width:100%` but that won't kick in here because of the blue box.
I already have an approach ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/23jwtxx9/), same as snippet below) using a wrapping div, which demonstrates the desired behaviour, but that would mean to wrap each content image in a div.

Is there any other smart way to do this without a wrapping div?

```css
/* try varying the width of #wrap to see the effect */
#wrap {
  border:1px solid #aaa;
  min-height:200px;
  width:280px;
  background-color:#ddd;
  padding:10px;
}
#blue {
  width:150px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #aaa;
  float:left;
  background-color:#ccccff;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin-right:10px;
}
#green {
  min-width:100px;
  min-height:30px;
  background-color:#ccffcc;
  border:1px solid #aaa;
  overflow:hidden;
  max-width:100%;
}
#green > img {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="blue"></div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.
  <div id="green"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"/></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach.

Say your side by side layout of the blue and green divs works until you reduce your viewport to 800px. You could use CSS and a media query like the following:

```
/* set default sizes for #green and #blue  */ 

#green{
 width:A;
}  

#blue{
 width:B;
}  

/* on narrow viewports resize #green and #blue and stack them one over the other  */  
@media (max-width: 800px) {  

     #green{
       clear:left:  
       width: C;
     }  

    #blue{
    width:D;
   }

 }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is more an adaptive than a responsive approach, and my hope was to find a really responsive solution. I'll see if I can find a good compromise, but I won't mark this as an answer for now. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Hi @z00l, depending on the specifics of your design and the elements on the page, options with this suggestion might be to use float:left; instead of clear for the #green div inside the media query, and instead of using fixed pixel widths for #green and #blue, use relative dimensions like % or vw.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="blue"></div>  
  <div id="green"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.</p><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not a solution for my problem. This would result in moving the text part below the blue box too, which is not an option. Thanks for the input though.